# Looping N size nested array

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have nested array and I need to loop second level deep nested array and do some match.

Loop friends array and compare reqs_status where user_id is the loggedin user ($id).

Json array shown below:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":8,
      "firstname":"Lauren",
      "lastname":"Lambie",
      "email":"lal30@org.uk",
      "role":1,
      "photo":"uploads\/5.jpg",
      "bio":"Surfer, follower of Christ, band member and Swiss design-head.",
      "friends":[  
         {  
            "id":8,
            "user_id":9,
            "friend_id":8,
            "reqs_status":2,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":23,
      "firstname":"Jar",
      "lastname":"Morrison",
      "email":"jm93@org.uk",
      "role":1,
      "photo":"uploads\/20.jpg",
      "bio":"Operating at the crossroads of beauty and intellectual purity.",
      "friends":[  
         {  
            "id":21,
            "user_id":22,
            "friend_id":23,
            "reqs_status":2,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         },
         {  
            "id":28,
            "user_id":21,
            "friend_id":23,
            "reqs_status":0,
            "created_at":null,
            "updated_at":null
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

## Edit

In My blade view I have :

```
@if ($user['friend'][0]['reqs_status'] == 1)
//do something
@elseif($user['friend'][0]['reqs_status'] == 2)
//do something elseif
@else
//do something else
```

Here I am not aware if [0] or [1], [2],.... is the right number because it is dynamic and the size of array is not fixed. I need a way to loop this nested array.

So I tried to break it into something like:

```
@foreach ($users['friends'] as $friend)
@if($friend['reqs_status'] == 1)

@elseif($friend['reqs_status'] == 2)

@else
@endforeach
```

I get error here: Undefined index: friends. so I was thinking how to make it dynamic [0] this part? or fix my code of foreach loop and if condition?

Comment: Could you try to paraphrase again **what** you want to compare? As you wrote, you want to cycle through the "friends" array of each 1st level element and verify if user with the "id" of the friend is online. Did I get that right?

Comment: @manniL All I am trying to do is that each user has list of friends array and in my view I need to find out in friends array which particular array object has user_id as loggedin user and if its req_status equals to 1

Comment: @manniL I have added code that I am trying to achieve. I get an error: Undefined index: friends

Comment: @manniL actually I just fixed my error it was suppose to be foreach ($user['friends'] as $friend) and not foreach ($users['friends'] as $friend) I am really sorry for this and thanks for helping anywayz